# Check memory usage of Safari in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, memory

How may I check the memory usage of Safari (or any other running process) in iOS on a device (not simulator)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run instruments, start up the activity monitor instrument, select the target to be your device and "all processes", and start the monitor.

Comment: I'm not familar with using this tool, I don't see a way to select a target. Are you talking about select a target with safari ?

Comment: Instruments is Apple's debugging tools suite which comes bundled with Xcode.